# Input is never used problem WHEN using VARIABLE in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

```
entity check_signalanvariable is
Port ( 
          i_cos_theta               : in sin_cos_type;
          i_sin_theta               : in sin_cos_type;
          i_w                       : in w_type;
          i_rst                     : in  std_logic;
          i_clk                     : in  STD_LOGIC;
          c                         : out  c_type);
end check_signalanvariable;

architecture Behavioral of check_signalanvariable is
    signal   en_MAIN_CACULATING  : in STD_LOGIC:= '0';
    signal   end_MAIN_CACULATING : std_logic :='0';
begin

Process (i_clk,i_rst)
    variable r_w            : w_type;
    variable cos_theta      : sin_cos_type;
    variable sin_theta      : sin_cos_type;

begin
    if (i_rst = '0') then
        c <= '0';
    elsif (rising_edge (i_clk)) then
        if (en_MAIN_CACULATING = '1') then
            r_w             := i_w;
            cos_theta       := i_cos_theta;
            sin_theta       := i_sin_theta;
            c               <= cos_theta + sin_theta;
            end_MAIN_CACULATING <='1';
        else
            end_MAIN_CACULATING <='0';
        end if;

    end if;
end process;
```

I have a PROCESS above. The Data types I defined in a separate library.
when EN_MAIN_CACULATING = '1', I want to sample some values such as : r_w, cos_theta, sin_theta.

I receive many warns : Input  is never used,Input  is never used,Input  is never used. when using PLANAHEAD software, all VARIABLES (r_w cos_theta, sin_theta) is lost.

I don't understand why. Can anyone help me ? Thank in advance.

Comment: Your variable r_w is never used and gets optimized away. Same might apply for Signal c.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain to me?

Comment: 1/ I don't see any inputs or outputs. Where are your I/O ports? 2/ It looks like you don't understand the phrase "...gets optimized away" in which case I recommend you read up on VHDL, hardware design languages and synthesis  in general.

Comment: Sorry you, I shortened the code to simplify. INPUTS are i_w,i_cos_theta,i_sin_theta . OUTPUT is c. I'm so sorry about the problem. I understand " gets optimized away" but I have a question is that the outputs is the function included i_sin_theta and i_cos_theta , but I still gets the warning above ? I hope you help me.

Comment: Update your question with the I/O. If what you say is true then `en_MAIN_CACULATING` is never set so few assignments take place so most outputs get optimized away.

Comment: I updated the question. As you said above. I get the warns "Input is never used" Because en_MAIN_CACULATING signal is never 1. But I got "Assignment to END_MAIN_CACULATING ignored, since the identifier is never used". Can you tell me why?

Comment: You have signal `end_MAIN_CACULATING` and you don't use it. Notice that having two signals named similarly: `en_MAIN_CACULATING` and `end_MAIN_CACULATING` might make debugging tricky for you.

Comment: end_MAIN_CACULATING signal is still assigned to '1' or '0' . Why is it not use? @Qui